# How to update subdocument with findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

there is a document in collection books :

```
{ _id : someMongooseGeneratedId,
  name : 'myBook',
  data : [{_id : 'page', name : 'one'},{ _id : 'chapter', name : 'Chapter One' }]
 }
```

I want to update books where book name is 'myBook' :
 Set name of chapter as 'Chapter 1' to the data where _id is 'chapter'

result as :

```
{ _id : someMongooseGeneratedId,
  name : 'myBook',
  data : [{_id : 'page', name : 'one'},{ _id : 'chapter', name : 'Chapter 1' }]
 }
```

I am looking to do the same with single query with mongoose.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following works for me :

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ name : 'myBook', "data._id" : 'chapter' }, { "data.$.name" : 'Chapter 1' });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot seem to get the above (elegant) solution to work. Syntax error on data._id as well as on data.$.name. Is this supposed to work on recent versions of Mongoose?

Comment: Ok, found out why it didn't work for me... adding quotes around data._id and data.$.name solved the issue. Works as a charm!